# Get url from chrome.tabs.onUpdated with activeTab permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

My extension works within one tab. The docs for the `activeTab` permission say that it temporarily grants `tabs` rights on the active tab. However, the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` method does not allow getting the url of the current tab in the callback. Can this be resolved without using `tabs` or host permissions?

Comment: The truth of `activeTab` permission is that it requires a user gesture performed towards your extension explicitly. Navigating a tab isn't such a gesture so you can't read the url inside onUpdated event. How exactly does your extension interact with the user? Describe the workflow and maybe we'll see if there's a solution.

Comment: @wOxxOm An user clicks on the link going from `example.com` to `example.com/foo`. The extension should receive url `/foo`.

Comment: Like I said, "performed towards your extension explicitly". Clicking a link in the page is not such a gesture. The approved gestures are listed in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#activeTab_permission). You'll have to use one of them.

Comment: That depends. If the extension works as content script, then you can get the URL in content script and then send it to background script using `sendMessage()`